# How to mock sync.Map in Go?

Tags: go, mocking

```
var pageCache sync.Map

func getCache(){
    appCache, ok := pageCache.Load(key)
}
```

I tried to mock through [gomonkey](https://github.com/agiledragon/gomonkey).

`patches := gomonkey.ApplyMethodSeq(reflect.TypeOf(pageCache), "Load", outputs)`

Goland has the following warning on `pageCache`:

Call of 'reflect.TypeOf' copies the lock value: type 'sync.Map' contains 'sync.Mutex' which is 'sync.Locker'

Comment: Why do you need to mock this? Most mocks I've seen are for things that require integration tests, but `sync.Map` is a built-in data structure. What are you trying to accomplish with a mock that you can't accomplish with the data structure itself?

Comment: I tried to assign value to appCache in a unit test case. @ClarkMcCauley

Comment: Yes but it's still not clear to me why you need to mock an internal data structure. Why can't you use the `sync.Map` data structure itself in your unit tests? The monkey patching mock will also not work correctly (see your error) because your implementation of the `Load` function does not work correctly with the Mutexes internal to the `sync.Map`.

Comment: Sry, I just need to store sth in advance.

Comment: From your post it is hard to guess what you trying to achieve. A unit test should not interleave with others and changes made during a test should not affect other tests.  Your snippet suggests that you have a singleton which is hard to unit test, because it is a global state, shared by all tests.

Comment: @XueSongYe You don't need to mock that map; mocking (and _test doubles_ in general) are typically useful only when interaction with the real world (network, DB, etc.) is involved, not for purely in-memory stuff. And you don't need to use reflection either, here. The difficulty you perceive stems from your `sync.Map` being a global (package-level) variable. If it were stored in a field of one of your struct types, and if you declared `getCache` as a method on that type, the problem would go away.

Answer (score -2):

Perhaps this would work for your use-case?

```
type MockedMap struct {
    sync.Map
}

func (m *MockedMap) Load(key interface{}) (value interface{}, ok bool) {
    // Do something with the call unique to this mock
    return m.Map.Load(key)
}
```

Your implementation just needs to accept a map interface rather than `*sync.Map` so that it can handle both the mock and the real thing.

```
type Loadable interface {
    Load(interface{}) (interface{}, bool)
}
```

Comment: Your mock isn't a mock, it's just `sync.Map` with a wrapper that doesn't do anything.

Comment: @Adrian See my comments to OP. I proposed this not as a true mock but as a side affect. You don’t need to mock an internal data structure, but you may need to run side affects for unit tests. The reason it doesn’t do anything is because OP didn’t specify what they needed to do. Notice my comment that explicit says “do something with the call unique to this mock”. I think that should be obvious.